# Date queries in monetdb?

Tags: sql, database, monetdb

I am able to do the following query

```
select (current_date-interval '1' day) ,a,b from (select '1' as a, 2 as b) as t2;
```

But I am not able to put variables in place  of '1'.
I have tried the following methods with no success

```
select (current_date-interval b day) ,a,b from (select '1' as a, 2 as b) as t2;
select (current_date-interval a day) ,a,b from (select '1' as a, 2 as b) as t2;
```

I have also tried casting but still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this:

```
select (current_date-interval 1 day*b) ,a,b from (select '1' as a, 2 as b) as t2;
select (current_date-interval 1 day*cast(a as int)) ,a,b from (select '1' as a, 2 as b) as t2;
```

So this question is answered :)